# How to get an exact match with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to do a scrape of various li's of a webpage but i encountered a problem, since i'm looking for the header of each section to save the data on a diferent sub object titles "Características generales" and "Características" are going into conflict, first one "Características generales" is working ok but the other is getting its own li's plus the ones from the composed title.

```
        const characteristicsHelper = $("[class='general-section article-section']");
        characteristicsHelper.each((index, element) => {
            //test2.push($(element, '.section-title > h4').text());
            if (($(element).find('h4:Contains("Características generales")').text())) {
                ($(element).find('li').each((index, data) => {
                    dwelling.generalCharacteristics.push($(data).text());
                }));
            }
            if (($(element).find('h4:Contains("Servicios")').text())) {
                ($(element).find('li').each((index, data) => {
                    dwelling.services.push($(data).text());
                }));
            }
            if (($(element).find('h4:Contains("Ambientes")').text())) {
                ($(element).find('li').each((index, data) => {
                    dwelling.environments.push($(data).text());
                }));
            }
            if (($(element).find('h4:Contains("Características")').text())) {
                ($(element).find('li').each((index, data) => {
                    dwelling.characteristics.push($(data).text());
                }));
            }
        });
```

Comment: use `else if` instead of `if`

Comment: the code is not finished i might have the same problem again, in that case else if wont cut it.

Comment: just be sure to test more specific before less specific. The logic can definitely be simplified - adding sample html will help you get better responses

Comment: *"in that case else if wont cut it."*: ?? Can you give an example where it wouldn't?

Comment: same problems aplies with else if... im getting the results of "Características generales"

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter:

```
$(element).find('h4').filter(h4 => $(h4).text() === "Características")
```

Comment: is not working, i get all the values of the 4 option with that.